# Output mapreduce jobs to the standard out instead of a local file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-streaming

I want to the run the hbase Export by not specifying outputDir  i.e.the local output file instead I want to stream the export job output directly to the remote host to avoid local temporary storage.

```
String tableName = args[0];
**Path outputDir = new Path(args[1]);**
Job job = new Job(conf, "export" + "_" + tableName);
job.setJobName(NAME + "_" + tableName);
job.setJarByClass(Exporter.class);
// Set optional scan parameters
Scan s = getConfiguredScanForJob(conf, args);
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(tableName, s, Exporter.class, null,
  null, job);
// No reducers.  Just write straight to output files.
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Result.class);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

some mentioned in the posts we can overwrite getRecordWriter() method of the formatclass but I didn't understand.